# How to evangelize Stack Overflow (Server Fault and Super User)?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, site-promotion

How to evangelize Stack Overflow at user groups, conferences, students and others?

What to mention in presentations?

Comment: Please don't bother mentioning me. No-one outside SO knows who I am. Really.

Comment: @Jon: That means all the guys discussing "C# in Depth" on Amazon are SO members? Wow!

Comment: @Jon: Sure people outside of SO know who you are. I talk about you to my family & friends all the time. But seriously one person actually thought the Jon Skeet facts were funny.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to "evangelize" is to simply use the sites: Ask great questions. Provide great answers.

You have already been extremely generous in contributing your time, and others will hopefully reciprocate, in a virtuous "pay it forward" cycle. Learn from others, while sharing what you've learned with others!

Sharing is of course welcomed -- the more the merrier -- but ultimately, you shouldn't need to satisfy anyone but yourself.

Comment: I was going to say this. So, +1!

Answer (score 8):

Are you getting paid?  Why even ask this?

I have passed on the word, of course.  That's pretty much all it takes.

Best line:  "You know [expert sex change](http://experts-exchange.com)?  Its like that, but it doesn't suck."

Comment: No, I don't get paid.

Comment: Why evangelize?

Comment: to spread the faith :)

Comment: Why link to experts-exchange. I thought Jeff would've added an easter egg to markup that would redirect all experts-exchange links to SO.

Answer (score 4):

I would like a sticker for my laptop!

Answer (score 2):

Google does it for you.

As Jeff says, Just add quality content.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to evangelize (unsuccessfully).  Of course, my target audience is the userbase for the SAS system and its set of languages (still very much alive and kicking after 34 years).  It's sad but true.  The primary source of "knowledge exchange" for SAS software is still the **[newsgroup comp.soft-sys.sas](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.sas/topics?pli=1)**.

Every time I try to direct people to the infinitely better model of Stack Overflow I get flooded with what essentially amounts to...

"We've been doing this for decades this way.  Get off my lawn you crazy kid!"  I'm 40 and I'm a kid to the SAS old-timers.

Sheesh!

Answer (score 0):

Convince the SO Team to open a store...I'll even design the first shirt ;)

That's me in the first cell, second row. Can you find skeet, and atwood? :)

[image]

Comment: I like this concept for a shirt, and I have to say that I like it even more that my picture is on it 4 times :-)

Comment: It was a quick mock-up :) In reality, you would probably appear once......un-marked bills, beneath the dumpster. I can make this happen ;)

Comment: On my T Shirt, I'd want my SO flair.

Comment: Yeah; of course that would drive up the cost of your shirt - and your flair changes pretty rapidly if you're a constant-capper like many SO'ers.

Answer (score -1):

[Are you on a mission from God?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080455/quotes) (OT: Jeff, if you read this: that was a link!)
Honestly, I do not want to be evangelized and I think other do not want it either. Tell them how cool the site is and they should check it out. But don't make things religious. Trust a roman catholic ;-)